# How to fix this android animation playing correctly the first time but not afterwards?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
if (wordDirection == "Right") {
            matchTextView.scaleX = 0f
            matchTextView.scaleY = 0f
            matchTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            val scaleXIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(matchTextView, View.SCALE_X, 3f)
            val scaleYIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(matchTextView, View.SCALE_Y, 3f)

            val scaleInAnimator = AnimatorSet()
            scaleInAnimator.playTogether(scaleXIn, scaleYIn)

            scaleInAnimator.duration = 400 // Adjust as needed
            scaleInAnimator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()

            val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
            animatorSet.playSequentially(
                scaleInAnimator,
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(matchTextView, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f)
            )

            // Add a listener to perform actions when the animation ends
            animatorSet.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    matchTextView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            })


            animatorSet.start()
        }
```

With the above code the animation plays correctly the first time it's triggered, it correctly zooms in and then fades. However, for any subsequent plays, the animation has no zoom in effect and the duration is shorter overall, it effectively only plays the fade out

Any help with this would be appreciated

I tried altering some values and monitoring the scaleX and scaleY but I cannot find the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset `alpha` as well with `scaleX-scaleY` property.

```kotlin
 btnGetSeriesTmdbDetail.alpha = 1f
 btnGetSeriesTmdbDetail.scaleX = 0f
 btnGetSeriesTmdbDetail.scaleY = 0f
 btnGetSeriesTmdbDetail.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

You set `INIVISIBLE` for view on `onAnimationEnd` and animate view with scale and aplha property. While reset animation property you only reset scale, reset alpha to 1F again it will showing animation every time perfectly.